# Why does Codeigniter automatically convert special entities in the form validation class if validation fails?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, html-entities

I didn't realize this until now, but when using the CodeIgniter form validation class, if validation fails ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE), all special characters in the post variables get converted, including any single or double quotes that were in the text inputs. Is there a way to turn off this behavior? I made pre-filling all forms in my project done with the html_escape command like so:

```
<input value="<?php echo html_escape($this->input->post('value'));?>" />
```

The html_escape ends up doing htmlspecialchars a second time, displaying the html entities in the form. I didn't set any rules to use "prep_for_form", and XSS is turned off, so I don't know why CI would choose to do this for me.

Also, I do know about the set_value function to pre-fill values, but in my case I'm doing something else that doesn't allow me to use that function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the codeigniter input class automatically does it.  I believe there is a config value you can change to turn that off called like xss_filtering or something.But why turn it off?

Comment: XSS is off, this is strictly prep_for_form working. What if I want to save the post variables in the session or database? The html entities will get saved instead of what I need. I want to be able to choose what gets converted and what doesn't.

Comment: if you want to save them in the session or database, you encode them before putting them in, and you decode them when you take them out.

Comment: Codeigniter's Active Record does that for me, it just escapes characters. It doesn't actuall convert special characters to html entities.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is just built in. If you want to turn off form prepping when form validation does not pass, simply extend the form_validation class using MY_Form_validation.php, copy the original run() function, and comment out the following code:

```
if ($total_errors > 0)
{
    $this->_safe_form_data = TRUE;
}
```